# How to add a button in lightbox caption area?

Tags: javascript, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm currently using lightbox2 to display a group of images, and what I want is to add a custom button in the `data-title` attribute, after I add it and the button shows, but I can't catch the click event of that button, when I click it and none of my code executed. Why is this happening? and  how am I supposed to make it work?

```
data-title='<a href="#" onclick="myfunction()">button</a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have `myfunction()` wrapped in a:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

or a

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

which is defining the function out of scope. If you can pull it out of the `.ready()` or `.load()` function it should work for you.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/35mrLqfq/)**

So to sum up, this works:

```
function myfunction() { 
    alert('it works!');
} 
$(document).ready(function(){
    //other stuff 
});
```

But this won't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function myfunction() { 
        alert('it works!');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I didn't put `myfunction` inside `ready` or `load`, actually I didn't use `lightbox2` at last.. thanks again:-)

Comment: or attach it to window

eg `window.myfunction = function () {}`